# Why do I have two different permission get dialogues in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, oauth

I have two sites in my Apps account and I've got them working for Facebook OAuth, why almost same FB login buttons lead to different permissions asking page.

First, not pretty page with permissions request from user and buttons **LogIn Cancel**.

```
www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=299921333363453&redirect_uri=http://www.weightfighters.com/&response_type=token
```

Second, the one I like more and want to have on my first site has pretty dialog page and buttons **Allow Don't Allow**:

```
www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=202378033138565&redirect_uri=http://www.loveatfirstsite.com/test/&response_type=token
```

The only reason I assume is different App settings in FB but they look same to me.
What could be a reason?

Comment: what diffierent permission you get for both dialogues?

Comment: I'm getting similar permissions but different design/layout of permissions dialog page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first one has enabled the new auth dialog

Check your app settings. For more information, please refer to this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Comment: Bingo! In Advanced App settings I had "Enhanced auth dialog" Enabled! Thank you!