# Authorization trouble with FB.login method

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication

When I ask for user authentication of my app, I use this dialog:

```
FB.login(function(response)
{
  if (response.authResponse)
  { ...}
  else
  {...}
},
{scope: 'publish_stream' });
```

My question is if the dialog is supposed to ask the user to login first and then ask for app authorization? Can i make the authorizarion dialog not to ask for login first? Since the user is already logged in to facebook?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has already logged in, FB will handle it and directly show the auth dialog instead of the login dialog

Comment: Do I need do check codewise if the user i logged in before auth? It doesn't seems to work autommatically?

Thanks!

/M

Comment: The api should handle it automatically.
And one question, do you mean that the wording on the auth dialog show "login" instead of "allow" even the user has logged in?
This problem may due to the new auth dialog, maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265343/why-do-i-have-two-different-permission-get-dialogues-in-facebook-api/8265864#8265864

Comment: The auth dialog first shows the "login" button and when pressed the second dialog appears showing the "allow" button. Is this perhaps the correct behaviour of the new auth dialog?

Comment: And, yes, "login" button appears even though the user is logged in.